# elasticdump index gives error "Error Emitted => <html>"

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to use elasticdump module to copy my production elasticsearch index to local machine by running command

```html
elasticdump \
  --input=http://localhost:9200/prod-index \
  --output=http://localhost:9200/local-index \
  --type=data \
  --ignore-errors \
  --maxSockets=5

But it only dumped the first 100 objects and then gave error like
Wed, 08 Jun 2016 22:35:30 GMT | starting dump
Wed, 08 Jun 2016 22:35:30 GMT | got 100 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 0)
Wed, 08 Jun 2016 22:35:30 GMT | sent 100 objects to destination file, wrote 100
Wed, 08 Jun 2016 22:35:31 GMT | Error Emitted => <html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

Wed, 08 Jun 2016 22:35:31 GMT | got 0 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 100)
Wed, 08 Jun 2016 22:35:31 GMT | Total Writes: 100
Wed, 08 Jun 2016 22:35:31 GMT | dump complete
```

Searched online for a few solutions such as configure the max sockets. Still not working for me. Any other solutions? Also my npm solution is 0.10.32. Does it matter?

Comment: Just hit this problem too.  Did you find a solution?